# redeploy code on Tomcat Server

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I am having 2 applications deployed on Tomcat 7 Server.

What should i do after redeploying java code on server

- Restart application using Tomcat Manager
- Restart Tomcat, but that will restart both applications, i want to
  restart only one
- Restart Server(CentOs6)

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  curl --user admin:admin http://localhost:8080/manager/text/reload?path=/myapp
  Doc is here 
  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Reload_An_Existing_Application
```